# How to translate this mongo query cmd using golang

Tags: mongodb, go

```
db.demo.aggregate([ 
{$group:{_id:"$name",
    a:{$sum:"$a"},
    b:{$sum:"$b"}}},
{$project:{name:1,a:1,b:1,_id:1,bdiva:{$cond:[{$eq:["$a",0]},0,{$divide:["$b","$a"]}]}}},
{$sort:{bdiva:1}}
])
```

I'm using   "gopkg.in/mgo.v2" as mongo driver for Go 
and I try translating this query cmd:

```
project := bson.M{
    "$project": bson.M{
        "name": true, "a": true, "b": true,  "_id": true,
        "bdiva": bson.M{"$cond": []interface{}{bson.M{"$eq": []interface{}{"$a", 0}}, 0, bson.M{"$divide": []interface{}{"$b", "$a"}}}},

    },
}

group := bson.M{
    "$group": bson.M{
        "_id":  "$name",
        "a":    bson.M{"$sum": "$a"},
        "b":    bson.M{"$sum": "$b"},
    },
}

sort := bson.M{
    "$sort": bson.M{
        "bdiva": 1,
    },
}
```

but I can't get **bdiva** right, how should I fix it?
------what I tried----
I execute the cmd in shell and get the result:
[image: bdiva is there]
field **bdiva**  is outputted,
but when I run the go code,it Only output:
[image: bdiva not found]

field **bdiva** is missing,why?

The complete code:

```
func AggregateQueryDemo() {
    println("//<<-------------------------AggregateQueryDemo start-----------")
    start := time.Now()

    session, err := mgo.Dial(ADDRESSPORT)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer session.Close()
    c := session.DB(DB).C(COLLECTION)

    project := bson.M{
        "$project": bson.M{
            "name": true, "a": true, "b": true, "suma": true, "sumb": true, "_id": true,
            "bdiva": bson.M{"$cond": []interface{}{bson.M{"$eq": []interface{}{"$suma", 0}}, 0, bson.M{"$divide": []interface{}{"$sumb", "$suma"}}}},
        },
    }

    group := bson.M{
        "$group": bson.M{
            "_id":  "$name",
            "sumb": bson.M{"$sum": "$b"},
            "suma": bson.M{"$sum": "$a"},
        },
    }

    sort := bson.M{
        "$sort": bson.M{
            "bdiva": 1,
        },
    }

    operations := []bson.M{project, group, sort}
    pipe := c.Pipe(operations)

    ret := []interface {
    }{}
    err = pipe.All(&ret)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
        return
    }
    for k, v := range ret {
        fmt.Printf("%+v: %+v\n", k, v)
    }
    fmt.Printf(" %v microseconds\n", time.Since(start)/1000000)
    println("//---------------------------AggregateQueryDemo end----------->>")
}
```

Comment: What is wrong? All I really see is the order of elements is reversed, so `[ "$a", "$b" ]` rather than `[ "$b", "$a" ]`. Of course you can keep going and wrap the `$cond` for the *'divide by zero"* check, but once you have worked out one part, it should not be hard to get the rest of it.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the code is updated.I will try step by step.

Comment: You could be more descriptive. Are you actually asking *"How do I mix BSON types and an integer/double value in array elements?"* That would be a lot more direct if you just were not sure how to structure the `$cond`. Again though, on the surface it looks correct, so I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: More details were added.

Comment: Should that not be `operations := []bson.M{  group, project, sort }`? You have the stages in a different order, therefore the result of `$project` does not come through.

Comment: It works!~~~~~~Thank you very much!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Query conditions are right written,and these are worth being noticed :

1. to writh $eq condition you should use interface slice in go
2. Operation Order is important, to fix issue of the problem ,it should be

   **operations := []bson.M{group, project, sort}**

thank [Blake Seven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5031275/blakes-seven)